# Blank/No xml preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have faced some Windows user profile corruption problem. However I have recovered that and opened Android Studio. In Android Studio previously it stuck at Initializing. Then I have reinstalled whole Android Studio. After installation and opening my project, XML preview looks like

[image: this]

### **Tried Solution**:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Clean/Rebuild project
- Deleting cache from `C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\` and `.gradle` & `.idea` from project folder
- Downgrading `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0` to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0`
- Resotre default (from Android Studio welcome page)
- Enable and Disabling `Experimental>Use new Layout Rendering Engine`
- Creating new project to check it is problem with engine(yes it is problem with engine not my project side)

### **Anyother solutions highly recomended.**

---

### Edit:

No error shown in IDE.

**My Android Studio details**

Android Studio 4.2.1

Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May 10, 2021

Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64

VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A

Windows 10 10.0

GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation

Memory: 1280M

Cores: 8

Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, Finally found defect

**Tip:**

> No error shown in IDE.

We can still find IDE Log for more details `Help>Show Log in Explorer` you can find `idea.log`. Check for error in `idea.log`

**My case:**

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Android\SDK\fonts\com.google.android.gms.fonts\directory\font_directory.xml (Access is denied)
```

As I said my user profile corrupted owner ship of `C:\Android\` is not changed causing `Access is denied`

**Solution:**

- Run Android Studio as `Administrator` or Change `ownership` of SDK.

Hope may help anyone

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am experiencing the same issue now and have been debugging for 4 hours. This just saved my life thanks!

Comment: Never run android studio as administrator. Go and fix the files permission from explorer :-)